# Convert a string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert a string to a DateTime for some hours now,
The string looks like this

`"20140519-140324"` and I know its in UTC

I've allready tried this

```
DateTime ourDateTime;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out ourDateTime);
StartTime.Text = ourDateTime.ToString("g");
```

and this

```
DateTime ourDateTime= DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
StartTime.Text = ourDateTime.ToString("g");
```

but none of these work. What I am not doing properly?

Comment: if you are sure that the date will always be in the kind of format yyyyMMdd then try split the string then deal with it

Comment: What about if you tring using yyyyMMdd-HHmmss?

Comment: @RamyMohamed: Why split the string, when `DateTime.ParseExact` accepts a format string?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for notifying i found your suggestion here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx , was lost from my mind since i almost didn't face a condition where i needed to receive such a date format .

Comment: @RamyMohamed: But the OP clearly does - and already knows about `ParseExact`. Splitting a date/time string into bits and parsing each part manually is almost *never* the right solution.

Comment: I usually use ParseExact and well , you're true. dunno what i was thinking then my mind went away to manipulating strings xD!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly.**

In your example, they are not. Use `yyyyMMdd-HHmmss` custom format instead which exactly matches with your string.

Here an example on [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string s = "20140519-140324";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt))
{
    dt.Dump();
}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/hdZJhX)</kbd>.

Your `DateTime.ParseExact` example also won't work because of the same reason.

For more information;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot everyone, many people answered this correctly, i wish i could mark all the comments as answers, i kinda though that yyyy-MM-dd was kinda absolute to be typed like that. Anyway cheers and thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format in the TryParseExact method.
the format parameter should be an indicator to the format of the input string.
therefor you need to do this:

```
DateTime ourDateTime;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out ourDateTime);
if(success) {
    StartTime.Text = ourDateTime.ToString("g");
}
```